# Most efficient way to cycle through all list[x]'s without going out of range?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, var

I'm passing a list that may have up to 6 entries. I need to assign each entry to a different var without going out of range if the list is shorter than 6.

so i need:

```
var_1 = list[0]
var_2 = list[1]
var_3 = list[2]
var_4 = list[3]
var_5 = list[4]
var_6 = list[5]
```

the var's can come pre-assigned None or (preferably) do

```
var 3 = list[2] or None
```

Comment: And don't name variables with Python types like 'list'

Comment: no dict because i need to preserve order of entry.

Comment: And?  Use keys with increasing numbers....your point is?

Comment: the list is set already. i need to assign var_1-3 to my_list[0]-[5]. if it was a dict, ya i could do var_1 = my_dict.get('1') but i like the list.

Comment: the list is ordered. dict is random order. must keep order

Comment: why not use OrderedDict then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dict instead.

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
dct = {'var_%s'%(i+1) : val for i, val in enumerate(lst)}

dct['var_1'] #accessing fist variable
>>> 'a'
dct['var_11']
>>> 'k'
dct['var_12']
>>> KeyError: 'var_12'
```

Note: If you really, *really* insist on having them as variables, you can do `locals().update(dct)`. But I don't recommend it.

Comment: Why the downvote? This kind of problem is generally solved using a dict.

Comment: Modifying locals() **does not work** (unless you are in the global namespace where locals() == globals())

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad idea to use `list` as a variable name, so I changed it to `lst`

```
var_1, var_2, var_3, var_4, var_5, var_6 = lst + [None] * (len(lst) - 6)
```